# VS code problems suggestion in C

Tags: c, c99

I am writing a HW for school, where I should implement a `circular buffer` and I ran into 2 things. *VS Code* says that:

1. too few arguments in function call [8,21]
2. expected a ';' [9,5]

But I'am quite sure, I have not made any mistake so far. I also don't know how to compile it, GCC won't take that. `Makefile` provided by school throws some error, but none regarding this issue.

I've got C/C++ extension form Microsoft [v1.2.2]. Are errors/problems handled by that one?

Here is the code *queue.c*:

```c
#include "queue.h"

// TODO - your code
queue_t* create_queue(int capacity){
    queue_t * q;
    q->capacity = capacity;
    q->count = 0;
    q->arr = malloc(capacity*sizeof(int));
    if(q->arr == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: cannot alocate enough memory!\n"); // here is the er#1
    }
    q->arr_end =(int*)q->arr + capacity * sizeof(int);
    return q; // er#2 occurs here
}
```

And here *queue.h*

```c
#ifndef __QUEUE_H__
#define __QUEUE_H__

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Queue structure which holds all necessary data */
typedef struct {
   // TODO - Include your data structure here
   int capacity; // the max # of elemetns, that can be stored
   int count; // # of elements in Q
   int * arr; // the array itself
   int * arr_end; // pointer to the end of arr (ie: *(arr+int*len))
   int * read; // position to read from; ie: HEAD
   int * write; // position to write form; ie: TAIL
} queue_t;

/* creates a new queue with a given size */
queue_t* create_queue(int capacity);

// ... 

#endif /* __QUEUE_H__ */
```

Output of the GCC for `gcc queue.c`

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And this is the `main.c` as is from school:

```c
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"

#include "queue.h"

/* allocate new integer with value a and add it to the queue */
void add(int a, queue_t *queue)
{
   int *p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
   *p = a;
   bool ret = push_to_queue(queue, (void*)p);
   if (!ret) {
      // free memory on failure
      free(p);
   }
}

/* print the int value on pointer p */
void print_int(void *p)
{
   if (p != NULL) {
      printf("%d\n", *((int*)p));
   } else {
      printf("NULL\n");
   }
}

/* pop from the queue, print and free the element */
void pop(queue_t *queue)
{
   void *p = pop_from_queue(queue);
   print_int(p);
   free(p);
}

/* get i-th element and print it (do not remove them) */
void get(int idx, queue_t *queue)
{
   print_int(get_from_queue(queue, idx));
}

/*
 * TEST PROGRAM
 * - reads commands from stdin and executes them in the queue
 */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int n;
   /* the tested queue */
   queue_t *queue;

   // read the size of the queue
   scanf("%d", &n);
   // create queue
   queue = create_queue(n);

   while (true) {
      char s[2];
      // read one command
      int ret = scanf("%1s", s);
      if (ret != 1) {
         break;
      }

      // add command
      if (s[0] == 'a') {
         int a;
         // read the argument of the command
         ret = scanf("%d", &a);
         if (ret != 1) {
            break;
         }
         add(a, queue);
         // remove command
      } else if (s[0] == 'r') {
         pop(queue);
         // get command
      } else if (s[0] == 'g') {
         int a;
         // read the argument of the command
         ret = scanf("%d", &a);
         if (ret != 1) {
            break;
         }
         get(a, queue);
      }
   }

   // remove rest of the elements in the queue
   while (get_queue_size(queue)) {
      void *p = pop_from_queue(queue);
      free(p);
   }

   // free memory
   delete_queue(queue);
   queue = NULL;

   // return 0 on succes
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: is line 8 the malloc?

Comment: `q` is supposed to point to a `queue_t` object, but you do not initialise it and it points to nowhere. In C parlance this is undefined behaviour, You need to allocate a `queue_t`, presumably with a call to `malloc`, and assign its address to `q`. Another very likely source of error is `q->arr_end =(int*)q->arr + capacity * sizeof(int);`. If `arr_end` is of type `int`, then no, pointer arithmetic doesn't work this way.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. is right about your `q` pointer being uninitialized, this will almost certainly segfault, but that isn't a compile-time error so that's not what's causing the errors you describe. please post the GCC log.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow Hi, that's what don't know, maybe malloc or sizeof.

Comment: As of your error messages, please show a [mcve]. That should contain all code necessary to reproduce the problem, including the header file, and all of the error messages, unedited.

Comment: @OliverK do you have `#include <stdlib.h>`?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Edited the question, hope that complies with the rules and should be done this way.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow, no, forgot to do that. Added but still did not resolve the errors.

Comment: This code does not seem to produce any of these VS Code messages. Perhaps you didn't post all of the code. If you edit any code before posting, please verify that the edited code still produces these same errors you are asking about. As for the `gcc` message, it tells you that every program should have a `main` function, which you did not provide.

Comment: I see, I thought that it's i minor thing I just missed, but might be a bigger problem.
My task is to implement functions for the circular buffer, it will be tested on a 'main.c'. So what I am trying to write is a library?
Will post the rest of the code, but i think that is too much lines for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please don't include conversational notes like "thanks in advanced[sic]" in questions. See [no thanks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it).

Comment: Yes you are essentially writing a library. You are supposed to post a [mcve], please note the word "minimal". You need to remove parts that do not affect the errors and keep the parts that produce the errors, not the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to reserve space for the queue:

```
queue_t * q = malloc(sizeof *q);

if (q != NULL)
{
    q->capacity = capacity;
    ...
```

Also

```
q->arr_end =(int*)q->arr + capacity * sizeof(int);
```

here you want (assuming that you want a pointer to  the last element):

```
q->arr_end = q->arr + capacity - 1;
```

pointer arithmetic is done in terms of elements (not bytes)

Regarding your compile error, it seems that you forget to include the unit containing `main`, try with

```
gcc main.c queue.c
```

Comment: this wouldn't be a compile-time error, though, and mallocing sizeof pointer is not the right size here. it would need to be `sizeof(queue_t)` (if the definition is known)

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow `*q` is `queue_t` so all is well here.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. can you dereference a pointer in its own declaration?

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow the argument of `sizeof` is not evaluated, no dereference takes place. It is needed only for its type. Yes this is totally legal.

Comment: @David Raniery, yes, i wanted to point to the end of the arr with `q->arr_end` . Thank you.